# How to add several tabs in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, tabs

Using official documentation I added custom tab in woocommerce:

```
/**
* Add a custom product data tab
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

// Adds the new tab

$tabs['test_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'New Product Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 50,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
);

return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

// The new tab content

echo '<h2>New Product Tab</h2>';
echo '<p>Here\'s your new product tab.</p>';

}
```

The problem is that if I try to add another tab using this code, then I get the error.

> The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 17:
>
> Cannot redeclare woo_new_product_tab() (previously declared in /var/www/html/sport-print.online/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(352) : eval()'d code:5)

Can you please tell me how to add another tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {
// Adds the new tab
    $tabs['desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );
}
```

Paste this code your active theme.

Answer (score 3):

I understand my mistake =).

Work code:

```
/**
* Add a custom product data tab
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

// Adds the new tabs

$tabs['new_tab_1'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'new_tab_1', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 11,
    'callback'  => 'new_tab_1'
);



$tabs['new_tab_2'] = array(
        'title' => "new_tab_2",
        'priority' => 12,
        'callback' => 'new_tab_2'
    );

$tabs['new_tab_3'] = array(
        'title' => "new_tab_3",
        'priority' => 13,
        'callback' => 'new_tab_3'
    );

return $tabs;

}

function new_tab_1() {

// The new tab content

echo '<ol>
    <li>content new_tab_1</li>
</ol>';
}

function new_tab_2() {
echo'
<h3>content new_tab_2</h3>';
}

function new_tab_3() {
echo'<p style="font-weight: bold;">content new_tab_3</p>';
}
```

The problem is solved.